# How to get the list of pods with container name for pods that have restarted

Tags: kubernetes, jq, kubectl, jsonpath

Using this command, I am able to get the container name that have restarted.

`kubectl get pods -o jsonpath='{.items[*].status.containerStatuses[?(@.restartCount>0)].name}'`

Is there a way to get the pod name as well in the same command?

Answer (score 2):

It's much easier to get json with kubectl and then process it with jq :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

kubectl get pods -o=json |
    jq -r '.items[] |
        "\(.metadata.name) \(.status.containerStatuses[]|select(.restartCount>0).name)"'
```

Answer (score 0):

I've not tried this.

If (!) it works, it's not quite what you want as it should give you every Pod name and then a list of Container names that match the predicate.

I think you **can't** use `kubectl --output=jsonpath` alone to filter only the Pod names that have a Container with restarts.

```sh
FILTER='
{range .items[*]}
  {.metadata.name}
  {"\t"}
  [
    {.status.containerStatuses[?(@.restartCount>0)].name}
  ]
  {"\n"}
{end}
'

kubectl get pods \
--output=jsonpath="${FILTER}"
```